# Python Enthought Canopy Word Scrambler

Tags: python

```
import random  

def word_scrambler(word):        
    a = word[1] 
    b = word[2]
    c = word[3]
    d = word[4]
    e = word[5]
    f = word[6]
    g = word[7]
    h = word[8]
    letterzz = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g]
    letterz = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h]
    letter = [a,b,c,d,e,f]
    lette = [a,b,c,d,e]
    lett = [a,b,c,d]
    let = [a,b,c]
    le = [a,b]
    l = [a]
    i = random.choice(l)
    j = random.choice(le)
    k = random.choice(let)
    l = random.choice(lett)
    m = random.choice(lette)
    n = random.choice(letter)
    o = random.choice(letterz)
    p = random.choice(letterzz)

    return i+j+k+l+m+n+o+p
```

What I am trying to do is create a word scrambler that will scramble an inputted word from the function.
I am not sure how to make it choose a random letter only once from each section of the word inputted. So like `[a,b,c,d,e,f,g]` and make it pick `g` only once and then it won't pick `g` again in the next search, and have it do that until it has used all the letters from the inputted word to make a random string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import random  

def word_scrambler(word):
    letter_list = list(word)
    random.shuffle(letter_list)
    return ''.join(letter_list)
```